# How to remove redundant code by using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I am learning web programming and AngularJS.  I have many redundant codes in the HTML file, but I don't know how to remove them.

HTML FILE:

```
<select id="selectSearch" ng-model="searchValue">
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
...
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">Class</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 1">{{ getClass(studentYear)   }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 2">{{ getClass(studentYear+1) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 3">{{ getClass(studentYear+2) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 4">{{ getClass(studentYear+3) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 5">{{ getClass(studentYear+4) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 6">{{ getClass(studentYear+5) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 7">{{ getClass(studentYear+6) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">Grades</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 1">{{ getGrades(studentYear)   }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 2">{{ getGrades(studentYear+1) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 3">{{ getGrades(studentYear+2) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 4">{{ getGrades(studentYear+3) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 5">{{ getGrades(studentYear+4) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 6">{{ getGrades(studentYear+5) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 7">{{ getGrades(studentYear+6) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">Status</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 1">{{ getStatus(studentYear)   }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 2">{{ getStatus(studentYear+1) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 3">{{ getStatus(studentYear+2) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 4">{{ getStatus(studentYear+3) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 5">{{ getStatus(studentYear+4) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 6">{{ getStatus(studentYear+5) }}</td>
    <td x-ng-if="searchValue >= 7">{{ getStatus(studentYear+6) }}</td>
</tr>
...
```

I think I need to use *ng-repeat* && *ng-init*, but I don't know how to use them in this case..

Comment: You should consider going through the [angularjs tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's pretty hard to actually understand what's the logic behind your tables, I've made a rather general example how you can use ng-repeat and ng-select to play with some data.

See the code below:

```
<div data-ng-controller="nodeTodayCtrl">
    <label for="selectYear">Select year you want info for</label>
    <select data-ng-model="selectedYear" data-ng-options="year for year in possibleYears"></select>

    <!-- we are assuming that there are in total of 9 classes and after that they've finished school -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Is in class on selected year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="student in students">
            <td>{{student.name}}</td>
            <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{ getClass(student, selectedYear); }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.possibleYears = [];
$scope.yearRange = 10;

// populate possible years, start from 0 to include current year
for(var i = 0; i <= $scope.yearRange;i++) {
    $scope.possibleYears.push((new Date()).getFullYear() + i);
}

$scope.getClass = function(student, selectedYear) {
    var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

    // default to current year
    if(!selectedYear) {
        selectedYear = currentYear;
    }
    var classIn = student.class + (selectedYear - currentYear);

    return (classIn > 9) ? 'Finished school '+ (classIn - 9) +' year(s) ago' : classIn;    
};

// your students data
$scope.students = [{}, ...];
```

Please see fiddle for working example with full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hpeinar/zwnbet95/

Answer (score 0):

An example:
      You have an array like, Arrayed=[{value:1},{value:2},{value:3},{value:4},{value:5}];

```
<select id="selectSearch" ng-model="searchValue" ng-repeat="single in Arrayed">
   <option value="{{single.value}}">{{single.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Here as you see the html code is largely reduced in comparison with yours.

Use this:[LINK FOR HELP](https://angularjs.org/)

Hope it helps.......!